# Difference between HttpTimeoutException and TimeoutException

Tags: java, exception, timeout

Can someone please help understand the difference between HttpTimeoutException and TimeoutException.

As per the definition of [HttpTimeoutException](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/net/http/HttpTimeoutException.html)

> Thrown when a response is not received within a specified time period.

And [TimeoutException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeoutException.html)

> Exception thrown when a blocking operation times out. Blocking operations for which a timeout is specified need a means to indicate that the timeout has occurred. For many such operations it is possible to return a value that indicates timeout; when that is not possible or desirable then TimeoutException should be declared and thrown.

Comment: HttpTimeoutException is a subclass of the general TimeoutException. You can catch an HttpTimeoutException with a handler for the more generic TimeoutException. However, using the more specific http exception is recommended over using a TimeoutException handler for code clarity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `Exception`s are a way of signalizing problems in Java. You can always use any any to show the problem, but it's a good manner to use Exceptions that will help to understand the issue.

Both of the `Exception`s you ask about extend `Exception` as all `Exception`s do. Why not to always throw `Exception`? Because it's more meaningful to poor developers to receive `NumberFormatException` or `NullPointerException` then a basic `Exception`.

Ok, so let's have a look at `TimeoutException` and `HttpTimeoutException`.

```
java.lang.Object
 java.lang.Throwable
  java.lang.Exception
   java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

java.lang.Object
 java.lang.Throwable
  java.lang.Exception
   java.io.IOException
    java.net.http.HttpTimeoutException
```

First difference we can see is the fact, that `HttpTimeoutException` extends `IOException` and the `TimeoutException` extends basic `Exception`. What it tells us?

We should use `HttpTimeOutException` when the problem is with the http client or server responding for too long as it's the I(nput)O(utput) problem.

One should use `TimeoutException` when the problem is computation taking too long, but not in case of http connection. Personally, I wouldn't use it for I(nput)O(utput) taking too long even if it's keyboard. I would declare my own `Exception` which would extend `IOException` and call it `IOTimeoutException` and use it to make it clearer for the future readers.

Hopefully it helps. Feel free to ask further in comments - I'll update my answer when desired.